# how do I use onClick, load, show to load div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have been trying out JS to make a button switch, show, hide text.

I have two buttons, register and login. When login is clicked, register will hide, vice versa.

Here is the link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wV7az/19/)

The code here..

HTML

```
<button id="btn1">Login</button>
<button id="btn2">Sign Up</button>

    <div id="login">
        <h4>Login</h4>
    </div>


    <div id="register">
         <h4>Register</h4>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$("#btn2").on('click', function() {
   $("#register").show();
   $("#login").hide();
});

$("#btn1").on('click', function() {
   $("#login").show();
   $("#register").hide();
});
```

CSS

```
#register {
    display: none;
}
```

It seems to not be working.. Register is display as none as I want to make login show up as default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `jQuery` first before using it.

It can be included under "Framework and extensions"

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wV7az/20/)